# Start and Stop websphere server remote

Tags: ant, websphere, websphere-traditional

I need script to start and stop web sphere server.

My requirement is need to write build.xml which I need to configure in Hudson
to start and stop web sphere application server.

I done all the tasks but to stop and start in the ant script not familiar.
Please provide any examples.

Answer (score 2):

This depends if you are using WebSphere Classic or WebSphere Liberty.  Both products have start/stop sever scripts, but they are slightly different.

**WebSphere Classic:**
start:   $WAS_INSTALL_HOME/bin/startServer <servername> 
stop:    $WAS_INSTALL_HOME/bin/stopServer <servername>

**WebSphere Liberty:**
start:   $WLP_INSTALL_HOME/bin/server start <servername> 
stop:    $WLP_INSTALL_HOME/bin/server stop <servername>

Once you know how to execute these commands manually, you can use the ant <sshexec> task to run the commands on a remote server.

```
<sshexec host="somehost" username="user1" password="pwd1" command="/path/to/WAS/bin/server start myserver"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following ant script for start and stop WebSphere Server:

```
<!--Stop Server--><sshexec host="websphere.host.IP" username="websphere.host.username" password="websphere.host.password"
        command="$sudo server_location/bin/stopServer.sh server_name" trust="true" />

<!--Start Server--><sshexec host="websphere.host.IP" username="websphere.host.username" password="websphere.host.password"
        command="$sudo server_location/bin/startServer.sh server_name" trust="true" />
```